# Find running COM server

Tags: windows, winapi, com

Is there any API to iterate through running class factories?

When a class factory is spun up and wants to register as available, it calls `CoRegisterClassObject()`. Is there a way to iterate all processes for all instances without knowing the CLSID for the object that it might have been registered for?

For instance, some system DLLs get loaded through svchost.exe and might have called `CoRegisterClassObject()` to make available the creation of an object that may or may not be published in the registry.

I don't think calling `CoRegisterClassObject()` necessarily causes some object to be put in the Running Object Table (ROT), otherwise I could at least start there.

So any way to iterate running class factories? And maybe discover the objects they can create?

Comment: No, you need the ROT.

Comment: There's no official way. You can use hacks: https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2022/06/finding-running-rpc-server-information.html . For example, run this tool https://github.com/silverf0x/RpcView and look for processes exposing the DCOM IOrCallback RPC interface (18f70770-8e64-11cf-9af1-0020af6e72f4)

Comment: *"running class factories"* - That's not something that exists. Class factories are discovered and asked to create objects. They aren't live objects. And they generally don't know whether they can create any given class until they are asked to instantiate it. Sounds like you are making assumptions that do not hold. What's the specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Awesome. A winapi question getting closed by three web devs that clearly didn't understand. Calling out users [devlin carnate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2359687/devlin-carnate), [SwissCodeMen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12632699/swisscodemen), and [Michael M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13376511/michael-m) specifically. None of you should have reviewed and voted to close this question.

Comment: @IInspectable Maybe my terminology is bad, but "running class factory" to me is when a process is running and some code has called `CoRegisterClassObject`. The class factory is available in running code...in contrast to an InProcServer32 where generally the exported `DllGetClassObject()` is called to get the class factory. I was investigating a security product that replaces Consent.exe with their own version. After investigating how AppInfo service launches Consent.exe, I was wondering what hidden COM servers AppInfo might have...and now it looks more like RPC. It's all investigatory.

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for your comment. For what I'm trying to discover, your comment about RPC may be the direction I need to head.

Answer (score 0):

When a client asks a server to create an object instance, the server typically creates a moniker for the object and registers it in the running object table (ROT) through a call to IRunningObjectTable::Register.

As far as I'm concerned, you could enumerate all the running COM servers with the running object table.

You could try to use `IRunningObjectTable::EnumRunning` method to enumerate all the objects currently registered in the running object table (ROT). And then use `IMoniker：：GetDisplayName Method` to retrieve the display name for the moniker.

Comment: The ROT only enumerates what has been registered with it, it doesn't "enumerate all the running COM servers". It's not a way to "find a COM Server" as asked in the question.

Comment: @SimonMourier That's correct. Word or some EXE COM server might put documents or the App in the ROT, but not necessarily the class factory that was made available by CoRegisterClassObject(). When say a VBS calls CreateObject("SomeProgId"), an EXE gets launched if it is an EXE server and the EXE calls CoRegisterClassObject() and then when the EXE is indicated to be finished with startup (often GetMessage() being the trigger), then COM tries to create the object with the registered class object. I was just trying to discover if there was an API to discover running class factories.